# How do I read a mainframe file which has no line delimiters?

Tags: spring-batch, ebcdic, fixed-length-record

I have a file which is very long, and has no line breaks, `cr` or `lf` or otherwise. In fact, there are no delimiters between records. Records are fixed length, and the record length and field lengths are known.

I know how to read a fixed length file in spring batch, but I am not sure how to configure a Flat File Item Reader to read a file so that it ignores `\n` or `\r` characters and instead terminates the line based on length. Is there some default way of doing this in Spring Batch? Or do I need to manually override the `readLine` method in the `BufferedReader` class?